# Migracion Automatica sql-server y Loopback

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

estoy trabajando una API Rest con loopback ya tengo la conexion creada con sql server, pero como puedo ocupar las tablas ya creadas en mi base de datos

Comment: Saludos bro, por curiosidad, ¿has visto la documentación oficial?

Comment: Hola fredy, pues estuve viendola pero soy novato aun no comprendi algunas cosas,tienes algun correo al que pueda contactarte y puedas brindarme una mano? te lo agradeceria

Comment: Considera que todos empezamos en algún lado. Edita tu pregunta agregando todos los detalles, aquí hay más chance que salga la respuesta , en mi perfil encuentras mi twitter :D